# Парсинг TSV файла, проблемы с кодировкой

Tags: java, кодировка, парсер

Всем привет!
Для парсинга TSV файла использую использую библиотеку [univocity]
(http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.univocity/univocity-parsers).
Конечная цель создать таблицу в UTF-16 (исходный файл тоже в UTF-16), для проверки пытаюсь вывести на консоль промежуточный вариант.

```
    TsvParserSettings settings = new TsvParserSettings();
    TsvParser parser = new TsvParser(settings);
    List<String[]> allRows = parser.parseAll(new FileReader(dataFilePath));
    String[] first = allRows.get(0);
    System.out.println(first);
```

Получаю результат в виде "[Ljava.lang.String;@776ec8df".

Если последнюю строку заменить на

```
    System.out.println(first[0]);
```

то ��1 (должно быть просто 1).

Если я правильно понимаю то проблема в кодировке, на каком этапе мне можно ее изменить для проверки, и нужно ли ее менять при условии что конечный файл будет тоже в UTF-16?

Comment: какой формат у dataFilePath?

Comment: String dataFilePath = "C:\\Users\\******\\IdeaProjects\\Generator\\source-data.tsv";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<String[]> allRows = parser.parseAll(new File(dataFilePath),"UTF-16");
```

Вот так все получилось.

Answer (score -1):

Попробуй так: `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(first[0]));`

Comment: Вообще так не скомпилируется, вот так получится 'System.out.println(Arrays.toString(first));' но результат тот же "[��1, 2 5 / 1 1, 02;>2  <8B@89]"